# In Android How to create web Service to store data in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, android, web-services

I am Develop on android application in that user fill up a form in they mobile and that data will be store in phpmyadmin. i want to create webservice in php for that. I am new to the webservices.
so please suggest some tutorial for that.

please help me to find this..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

PhpMyAdmin is just a frontend for DataBase (MySQL) managment. You can't store a data in phpMyAdmin. 
Try Kohana or Yii framework for create simple web-service.